# How to make buttons visible/invisible based on values in passed dictionary to tornado template?

Tags: templates, tornado

How to make buttons visible/invisible based on values in passed dictionary to template ?

```
self.render('menu.html',menu=menu)
```

where menu is passed like

```
menu = {'attack': False, 'intercept': False, 'follow': False, 'go': False, 'enter_village': False, 'send_backup': False, 'safe_zone': False}
```

and in template I have

```
    <div class="ui-grid-b">

        <div data-role="button" id="attack" {% if {{menu['attack']}} %}
             style='display:block;'{% else %}style='display:none;'{% end %}  >Attack</div>
        <div data-role="button" id="intercept">Intercept</div>
        <div data-role="button" id="follow">Follow</div>
        <div data-role="button" id="go">Go</div>
        <div data-role="button" id="enter_village">Enter Village</div>
        <div data-role="button" id="send_backup">Send Backup</div>

    </div>
```

and it doesn't work ( TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'), when I change to {{menu.attack}} I get error no key attack in dict ( but I passed that values and dict, I've debug to render point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax issue my friend.

Once you declare the tag **{%** you do not need the **{{ }}** declaration.

```
{% if menu['attack'] %}
```